# Get date from day/month/year and then get the name of the day (from generated date)

Tags: python, datetime

I just started with python and am trying to firstly get a date like:
date = datetime.datetime("13/1/2005")
But I can't get valid date... This is fixable...

The real problem begins whene i try to get the day name from valid date generated with datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creat a date from day/month/year like

```
d = [int(n) for n in [*date.split("/")[::-1]]]
d = datetime.datetime(d[0], d[1], d[2])
```

and whole answer:

```py
import datetime

date = "13/1/2005"

d = [int(n) for n in [*date.split("/")[::-1]]]
d = datetime.datetime(d[0], d[1], d[2])
dayName = d.strftime("%A")
print(dayName, d)
```

Output:

```
Thursday 2005-01-13 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

day = datetime.date.today()
print(day.strftime(f"Today it is {'%A'} {day}"))

day = datetime.date(2021, 12, 25)
print(f"Next Christmas comes in {day.strftime('%A')}")
```

output:

```
Today it is Wednesday 2021-02-17
Next Christmas comes in Saturday
```